# Как упростить проверку существующих переменных?

Tags: php

Собственно есть 4 переменные. Какая из низ задана - неизвестно. Действия для каждой переменной одно. Как можно получить заданную переменную, не проверяя отдельно каждую?

```
if(empty($first) and empty($second) and empty($third) and empty($fourth)){
  echo "Все пусты";
}else{
  //$desvar = ?;
  $que = "SELECT id FROM table WHERE id = ?";
  $prepque = $db->prepare($que);
  $prepque->bind_param("i", $desvar);
  $prepque->execute();
}
```

Comment: Скорее всего никак, но мало ли?

Comment: Эта часть кода у вас внутри какой-то функции?

Comment: @Pashok [`?`](https://ideone.com/9my72s)

Comment: @Deonis, Нет, просто в коде

Comment: @Эдуард, Кстати да. Это может сработать. Как только это правильнее сделать внутри else: Добавлять эти переменные в массив; Или как-то в строку их присвоить, а потом эту строку к нужному типу привести?

Comment: @Pashok а зачем вам else? М.б. вам нужно нечто [такое](https://ideone.com/DAPw7T)?

Comment: Или [такое](https://ideone.com/SAYpy3) ?

Comment: @Эдуард, Тогда действительно подойдёт. Учитывая то, что хоть одна переменная будет иметь значение. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как идея передавать параметры в виде массива, фильтровать его на пустые значения и сверять с исходным:

```
<?php

function validateValues(...$params)
{
    return empty(array_diff($params, array_filter($params)));
}

if (!checkValues($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4)) {
    // error
    echo 'error';
} else {
    // no errors
    echo 'no errors';
}
```

по умолчанию `array_filter` фильтрует `null` данные, если нужен какой-то другой критерий, можно передать анонимную функцию вторым параметром, где реализовать необходимую логику

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте функцию, передавайте в нее имена переменных, foreach перебирайте их и готово.

Comment: Так тоже возможно, но вопрос стоял иначе: "Как это сделать не перебирая каждую из них?"

Comment: @Pashok Всем бы хотелось ничего не перебирать, но таких методов не существует.